# All possible combination of dots between alphabets in R

Tags: r, combinations

I have a string "ab" and I want to generate all possible combination of dots between a, b. For example,

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

In this case there could be maximum 3 dots (no two consecutive dots) and minimum dots is 0. "ab" is just a toy example and the length of the string can be as large as 30.
I have no clue where to start. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a nice question, but you should update your question according to [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the example.

Comment: Please read linked post and post data using `dput()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is deliberately not a complete answer, but it's a very good start.

If you have `n` letters there are `n + 1` possible positions for dots, and `2^(n + 1)` as each position can either have a dot or no dot. You just need to iterate through those possibilities. We'll begin by generating these `2^(n + 1)` dot patterns using `expand.grid`:

```
input = "abc"
n = nchar(input)
dots = do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(c("", ".")), n + 1))
dots
#    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# 1                     
# 2     .               
# 3          .          
# 4     .    .          
# 5               .     
# 6     .         .     
# 7          .    .     
# 8     .    .    .     
# 9                    .
# 10    .              .
# 11         .         .
# 12    .    .         .
# 13              .    .
# 14    .         .    .
# 15         .    .    .
# 16    .    .    .    .
```

I'll leave to you finishing up - breaking up your input string into individual letters `strsplit(input, "")`, and using `paste0` or similar to combine the letters with the dots.

You say your input can have length up to 30. The result there will have 2^31 = 2,147,483,648 combinations, which is quite a few. You may run into memory constraints doing this in R, depending on your machine. I'd consider thinking about whether you really need to generate *all* the combinations. A usually better approach would be to use iterators (see, e.g., the `iterators` package). This could help you generate any arbitrary combination that you want, without requiring you to generate *every* combination.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. But I think there is one closing bracket missing in your code. I have tried with dots = do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(c("", "."), n + 1))) but getting wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to **[Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))**. Here, our letters are analogous to the stars and the dots are analogous to the bars:

```
## transform string into stars and bars format
ab

## add spaces around each letter    
_a_b_

## substitute stars (i.e. asterisks) for letters
_*_*_
```

Now, we simply ask the question:

> Given *n* spaces, how many ways can we fill those spaces with *0* to *n* bars?

As @Gregor pointed out, this turns out to be the sum of the binomial coefficients (assuming *n* letters):

```
sum(sapply(0:(n + 1), function(x) combinat::nCm(n + 1, x))) == 2^(n + 1)
```

With base R we can easily achieve the desired result:

```
myStr <- "abcd"
indStr <- strsplit(myStr, split = "")[[1]]
strTemplate <- vector("character", length = (length(indStr) * 2 + 1))
strTemplate[seq(2, length(strTemplate), 2)] <- indStr

strTemplate
[1] ""  "a" ""  "b" ""  "c" ""  "d" "" 

dotVec <- seq(1L, length(strTemplate), 2L)

dotVec
[1] 1 3 5 7 9

unlist(lapply(1:length(dotVec), function(x) {
    combn(dotVec, x, FUN = function(y) {
        temp <- strTemplate
        temp[y] <- "."
        paste0(temp, collapse = "")
    })
}))

 [1] ".abcd"     "a.bcd"     "ab.cd"     "abc.d"     "abcd."    
 [6] ".a.bcd"    ".ab.cd"    ".abc.d"    ".abcd."    "a.b.cd"   
[11] "a.bc.d"    "a.bcd."    "ab.c.d"    "ab.cd."    "abc.d."   
[16] ".a.b.cd"   ".a.bc.d"   ".a.bcd."   ".ab.c.d"   ".ab.cd."  
[21] ".abc.d."   "a.b.c.d"   "a.b.cd."   "a.bc.d."   "ab.c.d."  
[26] ".a.b.c.d"  ".a.b.cd."  ".a.bc.d."  ".ab.c.d."  "a.b.c.d." 
[31] ".a.b.c.d."
```